# Matching Type symbols in Scala

Tags: scala, reflection

I've asked a couple of questions regarding reflection in Scala the last few days, because it still seems new to me.

The new one is actually two questions that are related :

- How would you create a function that returns a different result based on the input type?
- Can you do the same with the `TypeSymbol` and `Type` objects returned by the reflection API?

Example (does not compile, but that's roughly how I want it to work) :

```
def result[T <: String] = "STRING"
def result[T <: Int] = "INT"

result[String]  // Returns "STRING"
result[Int]     // Returns "INT"

val type_symbol: Type = ...    // Get a Type object from a reflection
type_symbol match {
  case Int => "INT"
  case String => "STRING"
  case _ => "OTHER"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it's something like this you're looking for?

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

def someStringBasedOnAType[T: TypeTag] = typeOf[T] match {
  case t if t =:= typeOf[Int] => "INT"
  case t if t =:= typeOf[String] => "STRING"
  case _ => "OTHER"
}
```

Results:

```
scala> someStringBasedOnAType[String]
res11: String = STRING

scala> someStringBasedOnAType[Float]
res12: String = OTHER

scala> someStringBasedOnAType[Int]
res13: String = INT
```

Be aware, however, that using `TypeTag`s is thread-unsafe a the moment. As far as I know this should change in a few months, probably in Scala 2.10.2 (see [SI-6240](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6240))